# Error on code: "typeerror: '>' not supported between instances of 'nonetype' and 'int'" in RaspberryPi

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi4

I'm making a project with the Raspberry Pi, i'm trying to turn on a led with a DHT22, and i've got the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/pi/Documentos/Ejercicios/DHT22.py", line 25, in <module>
if temperatura >= 28:
TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'int'
```

My code is:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import Adafruit_DHT
import time

GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(22, GPIO.OUT)


SENSOR_DHT = Adafruit_DHT.DHT22
PIN_DHT = 17
PIN_LED = 22


while True:
    humedad, temperatura = Adafruit_DHT.read(SENSOR_DHT, PIN_DHT)
    if humedad is not None and temperatura is not None:
        print("Temp={0:0.1f}%C Hum={1:0.1f}%".format(temperatura, humedad))
        print(temperatura)
    else:
        print("Falla en la lectura. Revisar el circuito");
    time.sleep(0.5);
    

    if temperatura > 28:
        GPIO.output(22,1)
    else:
        GPIO.output(22,0)
```

What is wrong? How can i put "temperatura" as a int or something? I'm varelly new with Python

Comment: It means that `temperatura` is `None`. You checked for `temperatura is not None` above but continued with the compare anyway. What do you want to do with GPIO when `None`?

Comment: Thanks for the answer!!

I'm trying to turn on a led with the pin GPIO22 when 'temperatura' is above 28 and when is below 28 the led is turned off.
How can i  make 'temperatura' as an int or something who can make the comparison?

Comment: My guess is that you put the ` if temperatura > 28:` code under the `if humedad is not None and temperatura is not None:` test where you determined you have valid data.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer!
You give me a idea, but i only added "temperatura = float(temperatura)" before the "if temperatura > 28" and it works!

Thank you so much for the answers and ideas!